# How to check if CloudFormation template is correct?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I want to deploy an SQS queue from a CloudFormation template. Is there any issue with my template?

```
configurationQueue:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue'
    Properties:
      QueueName: configuration-queue
      VisibilityTimeout: 60
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 86400

SQSQueuePolicy:
      Type: 'AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy'
      Properties:
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: 2012-10-17
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                AWS: '*'
              Action:
                - 'sqs:CreateQueue'
                - 'sqs:DeleteMessage'
                - 'sqs:GetQueueAttributes'
                - 'sqs:GetQueueUrl'
                - 'sqs:ListQueueTags'
                - 'sqs:ListQueues'
                - 'sqs:ReceiveMessage'
                - 'sqs:SendMessage
              Resource: "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:****configuration-queue"
        Queues:
          - !Ref configurationQueue
```

This is the command I used

```
cfn-lint sqs-resources.yaml
```

and this is the error

[image]

Comment: You can [validate the template syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/validate-template.html) quite easily using the awscli but we can't validate the semantics of your template because you haven't indicated what the requirements are.

Comment: Hi, @jarmod I just wanna create a simple sqs ctf, is there any c error in my code?

Comment: No, it's almost certainly wrong but we don't know what 'right' is, because we don't know what you want to achieve. That said, obvious errors are the principal - you should almost never use AWS:*, but instead limit it to the minimal set of AWS accounts (your account number, for example). Actions should only typically include  sqs:SendMessage and/or sqs:ReceiveMessage - you seem to be confusing  an SQS resource policy with an IAM policy. Here are some [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-creating-custom-policies-access-policy-examples.html).

Comment: @WCY You could use cfn-lint, cfn-nag for your CFN template validation.
https://dev.to/namuny/using-cfn-lint-to-validate-your-cloudformation-template-jpa

Comment: @deechris27 I install   cfn-lint and test it , but get such error, is that because it can only used in vscode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqs:SendMessage` is missing the end quote

Recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see some of these errors inline while authoring templates along with autocompletion and documentation links

Comment: I install cfn-lint and test it , but get such error, is that because it can only used in vscode

Comment: `cfn-lint` can be used outside of VSCode as well